# Evaluating the integral $ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{(1+x^{2})(1-x^{2})^{1/4}}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I've been trying to find a way to integrate $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{(1+x^{2})(1-x^{2})^{1/4}}dx$ using contour integration, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a contour to use.

Since I have a branch points at $-1, 1$, and $\infty$, I need to have a branch cut that would connect all 3 of these branch points, which means I don't think I can use any sort of dog bone contour.

I also tried doing a substitution to try and make use of some sort of keyhole contour, but I was having problems with that approach as well.

Any suggestions on what to try?

Edit: This actually needs to be done using contour integration, it is not meant to be solved with other methods.

Edit: The most promising thing, so I think, is to have a contour that is a dogbone yet opens up on a line to infinity going down the positive real axis. So I have:

$* C_{1}$ Which is the top portion of the dog bone from $-1$ to $1$

$* C_{2}$ A small circle of radius $\epsilon$ around point $1$ traversed in the clockwise direction as $\epsilon$ tends to 0

$* C_{3}$ A line that extends from $1$ to $R$ as $R$ tends to $\infty$

$* C_{4}$ A circle of radius $R$ traversed in the counterclockwise direction as $R$ tends to $\infty$

$* C_{5}$ A line from $R$ to point $1$ going back towards the dog bone

$* C_{6}$ The bottom portion of the circle of radius $\epsilon$ around point $1$ traversed in the counterclockwise direction

$* C_{7}$ The bottom portion of the dog bone from $1$ to $-1$

$* C_{8}$ A circle of radius $\epsilon$ around point $-1$ traversed in the counterclockwise direction.

From here, I should be able to get everything to go to 0 except the integrals on $C_{1}$ and $C_{7}$, but instead I am stuck with $C_{3}$ and $C_{5}$ not cancelling like they should. I am not sure if this is just me having difficlty in choosing a correct branch or if I need an entirely different approach, but I feel like this is a better attempt than my previous ones.

Comment: the searched result should be $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{1}{4};-1\right)-2 \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{1}{4};-1\right)\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{3 \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}$$

Comment: Yes, I found that result as well, but I would have no idea how to produce that. I suppose it suggests some sort of series expansion (maybe?), but my knowledge on hypergeometric series is very limited.

Comment: The problem is, as you point out, is the branch point at infinity.  You can see this by making a substitution $x \mapsto 1/x$ and seeing the factor of $\sqrt{x}$ in the numerator.  Any detour around that branch point is sure to introduce a new integral which will end up being something like @mickep's integral.

Comment: @RonGordon Yes, I'm aware of the branch point at infinity. It has definitely been the main source of my issues. Is the way to fix it just an appropriate branch or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: And when you mention @mickep's integral, do you mean the integral before or after his substiution? I didn't really think the substitution would be of much use to me because I have not yet dealt with elliptic integrals.

Comment: Doesn't matter which one - I haven't done it out to be truthful, but I have enough experience to know how it should end up.  The point is that @mickep's integral provides the correct answer, and you get that by constructing the integral over the branch cut to infinity.  (Now, there is a residue from the poles at $\pm i$, so that integral may actually have a different form, but in the end, then result is the same.)

Comment: @RobGordon Sorry for any misunderstanding that I am having. His integral that uses the fact that the integrand is even I would think would have a problem since I am not making use of the branch point at $-1$. The integral he uses after substitution I am unaware how to take advantage of that. I would think having $\sin(t)$ under the root would create infinitely many branch points? And to clarify, when you say constructing the integral over the branch cut to infinity, do you mean using a contour that allows you to extend a branch cut to infinity and then having an integral to infinity?

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, all of the integration problems I have had to do have required contour integration to do them. The point behind them has been to practice coming up with contours, appropriate branches, etc. Even if there were other techniques that could provide solutions to them, they are methods I have not learned and kind of defeat the purpose of doing the problems.

Comment: this really one of the few expamles where contour integration isn't helpful. Comes this intergral from an homework problem?

Comment: This was a problem from a couple weeks ago, yes. The semester just ended for me, so I have had time to try and get explanations on things I couldn't figure out at the time. Contour integration was definitely something I had trouble with throughout the semester.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can express the integral in terms of elliptic integrals of the third kind
$$
\Pi(a,b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{(1-a\sin^2t)\sqrt{1-b\sin^2t}}\,dt.
$$

First, we note that the integrand is even, and thus
$$
I=2\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1+x^2)(1-x^2)^{1/4}}\,dx
$$
Now, let $\sin t=(1-x^2)^{1/4}$, and you will get
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{4\sin^2(t)}{(2-\sin^4t)\sqrt{1+\sin^2t}}\,dt.
$$
Now, we can do a kind of partial fraction decomposition to find that
$$
\frac{4\sin^2t}{2-\sin^4t}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1-(1/\sqrt{2})\sin^2t}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{1+(1/\sqrt{2})\sin^2t}.
$$
Thus
$$
I=\sqrt{2}\bigl(\Pi(1/\sqrt{2},-1)-\Pi(-1/\sqrt{2},-1)\bigr)\approx 1.80462.
$$
The numerical value computed with Mathematica.

Comment: I haven't really dealt with elliptic integrals yet. I like the idea and how cleanly that comes out, but I do need to use contour integration, unfortunately. Sorry if I did not make it evident that contour integration was needed.